# Eclipse Thym requires 'osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.jgit [3.0.0,5.0.0)' but it could not be found

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi, osgi-bundle

I am trying to install Eclipse Thym plugin, but I'm getting the below error.

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Hybrid Mobile Application Development Tools 2.0.0.201604091831 (org.eclipse.thym.feature.feature.group 2.0.0.201604091831)
  Missing requirement: Hybrid Mobile App. Dev. Core 2.0.0.201604091831 (org.eclipse.thym.core 2.0.0.201604091831) requires 'osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.jgit [3.0.0,5.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Hybrid Mobile Application Development Tools 2.0.0.201604091831 (org.eclipse.thym.feature.feature.group 2.0.0.201604091831)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.thym.core [2.0.0.201604091831,2.0.0.201604091831]
```

I dug through multiple forums, but no where it is clear on how to resolve this issue. How to resolve this issue?

My IDE is Eclipse Photon

Regards

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Eclipse Thym is not compatible with Eclipse Photon.

The key part of the error is

```
requires 'osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.jgit [3.0.0,5.0.0)'
```

which says that the org.eclipse.jgit plugin is required and must have a version of at least 3.0.0 and **less than** 5.0.0. The version of this plugin in Eclipse Photon is 5.0.0 so it is not compatible.

So it looks like you would have to use an older version of Eclipse to run this.

Comment: Hi @greg-449 Actually, i'm new to the world of eclipse. I will try out a lower version and let you know about the result. Thanks for the quick reply :)

Answer (score 3):

You could install it on more recent versions of Eclipse by using the snapshot software repository url, eq. `http://download.eclipse.org/thym/snapshots/`